# How to read last character of file through Batch Script and update the last character in a file

Tags: batch, batch-file, script

I have a very huge file in json format where each record end with "}}}," and same goes till last record where the last record comes like "}}}, " which has "comma(,)" and two spaces at end. Now what i want to achieve is the last record should be updated as "}}}" there should be no "comma" and paces coming at last record.

Attach a sample of last record i need this to be done through Bach script. I quick help would be much appreciated !!!

```
    [{
{"availabilityDate":"2020-10-07","status":"ACT"},"organization":{"id":"TMO1","code":"TMO1","type":"SUP","name":"TMO Process & Data","subType":"DEP",
"status":"ACTIVE","availablityDate":"2020-10-07","orgLevelFromTop":0,"orgLevels":[{"level":"0","orgCode":"TMO1","orgName":"TMO Process & Data"}]},
}}},
{
{"availabilityDate":"2020-10-07","status":"ACT"},"organization":{"id":"TMO1","code":"TMO1","type":"SUP","name":"TMO Process & Data","subType":"DEP",
"status":"ACTIVE","availablityDate":"2020-10-07","orgLevelFromTop":0,"orgLevels":[{"level":"0","orgCode":"TMO1","orgName":"TMO Process & Data"}]},
"job":{"profileId":2423532,"titleOfPosition":"Data Steward","managementLevel":"MG1","familyId":"32532532","familyGroup":"JOB1","familyName":"Data Mgmt",
"familyStatus":"ACT","status":"ACT"},"unionMembership":{"id":"21424221","name":"CAN - WEST - CALGARY"}}},  
]
```

This is what i tried :-

```
@echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for /F %%A in (%newfile) do (
        set mvar=%%A 
        set kvar=!mvar:~1,-1!
        echo !kvar!
        )
```

Comment: Do you want a batch to change all json files in a folder like that or just change one file? Cause if it is only one file it really would be easier to change it manually.

Comment: This may not be possible with batch, depending on your definition of huge. Batch cannot read lines that exceed 8197 bytes in length. It is not unreasonable for a JSON file to exceed that limit.

Comment: The solution is simple with the hybrid JScript/batch utility [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). `call jrepl ", *$" "" /inc -1 /f "yourfile" /o -`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bat
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion && set /a "_line=0, _skip=0"
set "_json=Source_File.json" && set "_json_tmp=%temp%\Json_Temp.json"
for /f tokens^=2delims^=^: %%i in ('find/v /c "" "%_json%"')do set/a "_skip=%%i-1"

for /l %%L in (!_skip! -1 1)do for /f tokens^=*delims^=^\* %%A in ('more +%%~L ^<"!_json!"
')do set "_str=%%A" && cmd /v /c "echo=!_str:~-6!|findstr "}}},.."|find ",  "">nul && (
     set/a "_line=%%~L+1" && goto %:^)
    )

%:^)
for /f ^eol^=*^usebackq^tokens^=*delims^=^\* %%A in ("!_json!"
)do set _str=<nul & set "_str=%%A" & >nul set/a "_cnt+=1" && 2>nul (
     >>"!_json_tmp!" (if !_cnt! equ !_line! (echo=!_str:~,-3!
        )else echo=!_str!)
    )

type "!_json_tmp!" >"!_json!" && del/q "!_json_tmp!"
timeout /t -1|type "!_json!" && endlocal & goto :EOF
```

---

- **Obs.:** Assuming the `file_script.bat` is in the same folder as your `file.json`
  _ _
- Basically inverts the listing using a numeric loop, where it operates in a negative way, if the file has 10 lines, the loop would start from 10 -1 of 1 in 1, list from the last to the first line, and another `for /f` loop to check if the line ends with these characters you need to remove:

---

**1.** Enter the folder where your `.json` file is:

```bat
... cd /d "%~dp0"
```

**2.** For double `for` loops, you need to enable `enabledelayedexpansion`:

```bat
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion ...
```

**3.** Define the values ​​of variables to 0, prevention against possible errors in aborted executions, etc ...

```bat
... set /a "_line=0, _skip=0"

rem :: is the same ::
set _line=0
set _skip=0
```

**4.** Edit and add your file name, or preferably the full path

```bat
set "_json=Source_File.json" ...
```

**5.** Only a path and file name for temporary use that will receive the relevant editions:

```bat
set "_json_tmp=%temp%\Json_Temp.json" ...
```

**6.** To count the lines in the file and set (-1) to start the search for the last occurrence `}}},` in order of the last line to the first, searching the last line, second last line, and so on, within the current loop:

```bat
for /f tokens^=2delims^=^: %%i in ('find/v /c "" "%_json%"')do set /a "_skip=%%i-1"
```

**7.** Use a `for /L` loop starting in total (from total lines -1), allowing you to scroll through the file from the last line to the first, already using a `for /F` with `[more SKIP %%L]`, to skip those in the order mentioned above, also to use and define the last line (of the "time") in the `_str` variable:

```bat
for /l %%L in (!_skip! -1 1)do for /f tokens^=*delims^=^\* %%A in ('more +%%~L ^<"!_json!"
')do set "_str=%%A"...
```

**8.** Once `_str` contains the current line, in the reverse order of the lines listed in the file, only the last 6 digits are used to check the first occurrences of the strings to be removed from the line, if `fidnstr` + `find` `returns 0`, you save the line occurrence (last one/line number), and add `+1` to this line variable, in order to leave the current loop immediately to make use of that line/number in the `label %:^)`, using with `if | else` condition:

```bat
... cmd /v /c "echo=!_str:~-6!|findstr "}}},.."|find ",  "">nul && (
     set /a "_line=%%~L+1" && goto %:^)
    )
```

**9.** Once inside the label, line by line is saved in `_str`, using `for /f`, just as a counter (`_cnt`) is implemented in order to make it possible to filter the line accordingly ...

```bat
%:^)
for /f ^eol^=*^usebackq^tokens^=*delims^=^\* %%A in ("!_json!"
)do set _str=<nul & set "_str=%%A" & >nul set/a "_cnt+=1"
```

**10.** For each line in this `for /F` loop, `if | else` checks whether the line is intended for alterations, and echoes pertinently, subtracting the last 3 (`echo=!_str:~,-3!`) digits, if the line is different, echoes the current line without changes:

```bat
>>"!_json_tmp!" (if !_cnt! equ !_line! (echo=!_str:~,-3!
        )else echo=!_str!)
```

**11.** They temporarily file intended to save the lines with/without changes overwrites the files originally at the end of executions:

```bat
type "!_json_tmp!" >"!_json!" ...
```

**12.** Remove the temporary file, then use a timeout *in `wait indefinitely for a key press.`* But redirected to `type` command of the source file updated  file for a brief display of the result on the screen, after the execution is finished.

```bat
del/q "!_json_tmp!"
timeout /t -1|type "!_json!" && endlocal & goto :EOF
```

---

**Obs.:** if you don't want this display:

```bat
del/q "!_json_tmp!"
timeout /t -1|type "!_json!" &&  endlocal & goto :EOF
```

---

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`Cd /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)
- [`If /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)
- [`Set /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for)
- [`More /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/more.html)
- [`Find /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)
- [`Type /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)
- [`Timeout /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html)
- [`Findstr /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html%5D)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html%5D) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html%5D)
- [`Local Environment | Function`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-functions.html)

  - [`Setlocal`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) & [`Endlocal`](https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html)
- [DOS Tips Substrings Operator](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)

  - [`var:~x`](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php), [`var:~-y`](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php), [`var:~x,y`](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php), [`var:~x,-y`](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

Comment: Thanks this code resolved my issue!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Put the path or name of old json if in same folder as batch here:
set OldJson=Old.json

:: Put the path or name of new json if in same folder as batch here:
set NewJson=New.json

For /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%OldJson%") do (
echo %%a | find /i "}}}"
IF !errorlevel! EQU 0 set /a Occurances+=1
)

For /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%OldJson%") do (
set "Line=%%a"
set "Line:&=^&"
set "Line:<=^<"
set "Line:>=^>"
set "Linechange=!Line:}}},  =}}}!"
echo %%a | find /i "}}}"
IF !errorlevel! EQU 0 set /a Counter+=1
IF not !Counter! EQU !Occurances! (echo !Line!>>"%NewJson%") else (echo !LineChange!>>"%NewJson%")
)
```

Comment: Hi Ricardo, the solution is actually replacing all the occurrence throughout the file but i want it to replace only the last occurrence if suppose there is [{data1},{data2},{data3},  ] so we want only the last {data3}, --> {data3} without "," and spaces.

Comment: Ah ok, I thought that only the last occurance could possibly have "}}},  "

Comment: Please check the changes to my answer...

Comment: Take the last **`}}},  `** does not mean that it occurs in the last **`}}}`**

Comment: @ItWasntMe I have must missed something than, I don't know anything about json files....